# Error when trying to read_html from a website with delayed loading

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the public consultations from the European Commission's website with R for my master thesis. However, the loading function in the first second when opening the website seems to prevent this.

By running

```
test <- read_html("https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/better-regulation/have-your-say/initiatives")
```

I get the following error:

```
Fehler in readBin(3L, "raw", 65536L) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

*("Fehler in" translates to "error in")*

I couldn't find a solution yet and also struggle to identify the specific problem because I would actually expect the function the return the HTML of the loading screen that appears in the first second.

Does anyone have an idea how to get beyond the loading part with R?

Comment: You might have to use `RSelenium` to scrape the data from this webpage.